# Drop down Menu & right Click on list item in Xamarin.Forms UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am struggling to show drop down menu on click of image and also right click and show menu on list view row.
I managed to get something with the help of relative layout and frames but it is taking space and also not coming into correct position.

Here is what I have managed to get
[image: Current Screen]

But I have to make it something like below. Space should be removed. The menu should come over stack layout. IS there any way to make it over stacklayout? something like below
[image]

Also in the list shown below, I want to add right click and show menu option which also requires showing Frame or other layout over list view. See below image. Any help or example will help me a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Drop down Menu & right Click on list item in Xamarin.Forms UWP

Xamarin `ViewCell` has `ContextActions` property that could use to response ListView item right click. Unfortunately, the MenuItem is hard to custom.

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem Text="Add" Clicked="Add_Clicked"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Text="Delete" Clicked="Delete_Clicked"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Text="Edit" Clicked="Edit_Clicked"></MenuItem>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

For your scenario, we suggest to custom `ListViewRender`, and listen `ListViewItem` right click event then call a popup. For more code please refer the following.

**Forms client**

```
public class CustomListView :ListView
{
    public event ItemRightTappedEventHandler ItemRightTapped;
    public void RaiseItemRightTapped(ItemRightTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemRightTapped != null)
            this.ItemRightTapped(this, e);
    }

}
public delegate void ItemRightTappedEventHandler(object sender, ItemRightTappedEventArgs e);
public class ItemRightTappedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    #region Fields

    private object itemData = null;

    private Point position;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public ItemRightTappedEventArgs(object itemData, Point position)
    {
        this.itemData = itemData;
        this.position = position;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Property

    public object ItemData
    {
        get { return itemData; }
    }

    public Point Position
    {
        get { return position; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**UWP Client**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomListView), typeof(CustomListViewRender))]

namespace DropDownMenuTest.UWP
{
    public class CustomListViewRender : ListViewRenderer
    {
        ListView listView;
        Xamarin.Forms.ITemplatedItemsView<Xamarin.Forms.Cell> TemplatedItemsView => Element;
        object clickItemdataContext;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            listView = Control as ListView;
            if (Control != null)
            {
                listView.Loaded += ListView_Loaded;
            }

        }
        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }
        private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            listView.RightTapped += ListView_RightTapped;

        }

        private void ListView_RightTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var orig = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
            int index = -1;


            // Work our way up the tree until we find the actual list item
            // the user tapped on

            while (orig != null && orig != List)
            {
                var lv = orig as ListViewItem;
                if (lv != null)
                {
                    index = TemplatedItemsView.TemplatedItems.GetGlobalIndexOfItem(lv.Content);
                    clickItemdataContext = listView.ItemFromContainer(lv);
                    break;
                }

                orig = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(orig);
            }

            if (index > -1)
            {
                var point = e.GetPosition(listView);

                OnListItemClicked(clickItemdataContext, new Xamarin.Forms.Point(point.X, point.Y));
            }

        }

        void OnListItemClicked(object context, Xamarin.Forms.Point point)
        {
            var tappedEventArgs = new ItemRightTappedEventArgs(context, new Xamarin.Forms.Point(point.X, point.Y));
            var customListView = Element as CustomListView;
            customListView.RaiseItemRightTapped(tappedEventArgs);

        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<local:CustomListView
    x:Name="MainListView"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    ItemRightTapped="MainListView_ItemRightTapped"
    >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Label
                        FontSize="25"
                        Text="{Binding .}"
                        TextColor="Navy"
                        />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</local:CustomListView>

private void MainListView_ItemRightTapped(object sender, ItemRightTappedEventArgs e)
{
// show popup view
}
```